# combobox binding in a listviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` declared like this :

```
<ListView x:Name="lvRSU" Margin="3" Background="#84978F" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding rsus}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} Path" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22" Height="22" MaxHeight="22" MaxWidth="22" ToolTip="Open .rsu file" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                      <Image Source="Resources/Folder16.png" Stretch="Uniform" ></Image>
                </Button>
                <CheckBox Grid.Column="3"  Content="En" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding sensorTypes}" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                          <DataTemplate>
                               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                          </DataTemplate>
                     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                 </ComboBox>
                 <CheckBox Grid.Column="5"  Content="{Binding Name}" ContentStringFormat="Inv {0}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,1,1,1"/>
              </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and in the .cs file i have the following connection :

```
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> _sensorTypes = 
      new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string>(new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2"});

public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<string> sensorTypes
{
    get { return _sensorTypes; }
}
```

also i set the `DataContext` for my ListView :

```
lvRSU.DataContext = this;
```

But i can't get the items in my combobox at all. Maybe there is a problem because it's inside the grid ?

It's ok i got it now.

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView},Path=DataContext.sensorTypes}"
```

This one made the difference. I am going to the DataContext of the ListView which contains at some point my combobox, and i set the Path from there. Thanks.

Comment: the combobox is filled with anything at all?

Comment: you had ItemsSource="{Binding rsus}" in listView. what is rsus? Does that contain a prop sensortypes?  the binding should be more clearer than the one in your solution!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find anything wrong in your code.
So my suggestion is that you can use this method to debug the data binding: [Debug DataBinding using IValueConverter](http://wpftutorial.net/DebugDataBinding.html)

Hope that you can find the bug and tell everyone. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be:

```
lvRSU.DataContext = this.sensorTypes;
```

or preferrably bind it in XAML, as you noticed:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding sensorTypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
```